# When I create an account in web3.js, it is not reflected on the geth.ipc side

Tags: go-ethereum

I confirmed web3.js and geth.ipc is completely connected with right rpcURL.

on javascript side,

> web3.eth.accounts.create()

it creates new account with address.

but on geth.ipc side,

> eth.accounts

nothing shows up.

Where my new account was saved?

Answer (score 0):

When using `web3.js`, the accounts are created locally by the library. It doesn't use geth's rpc to generate new accounts (and you should never).

From the [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#create), you can see that your account details are simply returned by `web3.js`.

Comment: So... how to connect between them?I want to send eth to newly created account, I'm creating DAPP give faucet for new user on reactjs.
I can send eth to a new account created on metamask but can't send to new account created on web3.js.

Comment: Well, you have all the information about that new account in the returned value from your `web3.eth.accounts.create`. Then you can use the [appropriate call](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.0/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction) from `web3` to send the eth